# lyx with background won't load unless I type \newpage after the text

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx, compiling, backgrounds, rendering

I try to write a document with a background in lyx, I made sure it works on Texmaker, on Texmaker it needed to be built a couple of times and then it got it right but when I try to preview or export it on lyx it fails and I get blank pages, but when I put in ERT `\newpage` it's capable of showing only the page from above (but only one) but if I want it to show me all of the pages I need to check page by page when It needs to break. I add my Latex code, my lyx code and it's preamble. (It's easy for me to work with lyx because I need to put a lot of equations and other languages so keep doing stuff with latex alone is not an option for me)
Thank You.

**Latex code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{culmus}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[placement=top,angle=0,color=black,scale=4,hshift=60,vshift=-5]{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] 
        \draw [xshift=4mm,color=black,line width=1pt,rounded corners=7pt]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (.5cm,-.5cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-.5cm,.5cm) $);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \draw[color=black] (0,-2.5) rectangle (-1.3,-0.7);
    \draw[color=black] (-0.9,-1.1) node {\large\thepage};
    \draw[color=black] (-0.4,-2.1) node {\large\pageref{LastPage}};
    \draw[color=black] (-0.2,-0.9) -- (-1.1,-2.3);
\end{tikzpicture}},placement=center,angle=0,opacity=1,scale=1,position =current page.north west }
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
Here the text
\end{document}
```

**Lyx code**

```
Preamble:
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{lastpage}
    \date{}                
    \usepackage[placement=top,angle=0,color=black,scale=4,hshift=60,vshift=-5]{background}               
    \usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=0.5cm,right=2cm,left=2cm,heightrounded]{geometry}

ERT:
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\backgroundsetup{contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw [xshift=4mm,color=black,line width=1pt,rounded corners=7pt]($ (current page.north west) + (0.3cm,-0.3cm) $) rectangle ($ (current page.south east) + (-0.3cm,0.3cm) $);
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \draw[color=black] (0,-2.5) rectangle (-1.3,-0.7); 
        \draw[color=black] (-0.9,-1.1) node {\large\thepage};
        \draw[color=black] (-0.4,-2.1) node {\large\pageref{LastPage}};
        \draw[color=black] (-0.2,-0.9) -- (-1.1,-2.3);
        \end{tikzpicture}},placement=center,angle=0,opacity=1,scale=1,position =current page.north west }
        \pagestyle{empty}
                some text out side ERT
        ERT: \newpage
```

Comment: I took your latex code and ran `pdflatex` directly on it (I had to remove loading of culmus though) three times and got what I believe to be what you expected as the output. I then opened LyX 2.1.1 on Ubuntu and went to file > import > LaTeX (plain) and viewed the output and it produced the same output as running pdflatex manually. Did you try importing the `.tex` file? In the future, when you post your .lyx example (which is indeed a great idea!) just post the entire .lyx file. It's just text, after all.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie so I didn't know that I could just open the .lyx with a notepad as plain text (I only read some documantaions and it wasn't mentioned there). I'm amazed, I tried to add the ERT to the preamble and it didn't show and progress (I still needed to write `\newpage` every page), but when I imported it to LaTex and opened with Lyx it worked, I look at both of the files as text and I do see some differences. but know (of course) It won't work with hebrew (culums), I tried changing the language of the document but It didn't help. any Ideas of how to make it work? Thank You Very Much

Comment: I'm a little confused. From what I understand you only care about your other question now and this one is irrelevant, right? If so, we should add a solution and carry discussion on over there.

Comment: This is ancient now, but in general always place `\usetikzlibrary` in the preamble, not the document.